# OCaml: accessing a type in the Stdlib

Tags: ocaml

I want to use the Stack module from the Stdlib of OCaml, but I also need a membership function, which the Stack module lacks. So, following https://dev.realworldocaml.org/files-modules-and-programs.html, I created a file `stack1.ml` reading:

```
include Stack
let mem a t = List.mem a t.c
```

since `c` is the name of the record used in `stack.ml` (that file contains the line: `type 'a t = { mutable c : 'a list; mutable len : int; }`). But I get:

```
Error: Unbound record field c
```

What can I do ?
(And also: do I need a file with a different name `Stack1` ? This is a bit annoying for the files calling it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the type `'a Stack.t` is implemented using a mutable list or any other data type is an implementation detail that is abstracted away by the interface of the `Stack` module.

In other words, outside of the `Stack` module, you can only use the functions provided by the stack module that works on the abstract type `'a Stack.t` independently of this implementation.

Fortunately, those functions are more than enough to implement a `mem` function. For instance, with a `fold`:

```
let mem x s = Stack.fold (fun acc y -> acc || x = y) false s
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks indeed like `Stack.fold` permits to do everything that one could do by accessing the private field. But is there a loss of efficiency ? (It looks like not, since in both cases you iterate over the list, but I'm not sure there are no hidden costs.)

Comment: There is no loss of efficiency.

Comment: There is no loss of efficiency, but using a stack for testing membership is inherently inefficient. If performance of membership is critical in your application, you should either use a better data structure (possibly a treap), or use a stack (for stack operations) coupled with a Set (for membership testing).